# JOOQ join two tables with same column names

Tags: jooq

I'm using running following JOOQ query:

```
dsl.select().from(table).join(joinTable).on(joinCondition).where(condition).fetchInto(entityClass);
```

Both table and joinTable have id as primary key name, but resulting fetch into entity class contains id of joinTable, and rest of columns of table. If I reorder tables, result is similar, I have ID from table and rest of columns from joinTable.

Comment: Don't you generate the Metamodel with jOOQ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metamodel is generated using jooq-codegen-maven plugin.
Interesting, I found out that using:

```
dsl.select(table.fields())...
```

solves problem. I would expect that this behavior is by default, but it is not.

Comment: Why did you expect this to be the default behaviour? You joined a table, why would its columns not be projected by default?

Comment: Because I executed .fetchInto(entityClass) at the end, so I expected jooq would extract joined columns belonging to entityClass to construct entity class object.

Comment: I see, but that would be very confusing in lots of cases where you don't want that behaviour, including even if you had `DISTINCT` in your query, or unions, etc... The SQL projection (`SELECT` clause) and the mapping (`fetch` method) are independent of one another.

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder , I understand now.